# jQuery show, fadeIn, queue

Tags: jquery, show, fadein

I've got an HTML form. The user can click on, let's say, 2 buttons:
1 - The first buttons fires an oData request to the server (it's not really AJAX)
2 - The second buttons fires some other logic.

Now I would like to show a progress bar when action 1) or action 2) is executed.

In case of action 2) I've used `$(loadingImageId).show()` but this does not work, it's like if it's not executed immediately. However, if I use:

```
                        $(loadingImageId).fadeIn().queue(function(next) {
                        next();
                        self.onSaveOrderPress(oEvent);
                    });
```

It works as expected. Can anyone explain why `show()` does not work and `fadeIn()` does?
Besides, when the computation ends a pop-up is shown (and it takes a few milliseconds to show up in the screen). During this waiting time my spinning wheel (animated gif) freezes. Is there a way to prevent this?

Finally, how can I catch my oData requests? I've tried `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop`and they correctly catch all of my AJAX requests. But in my case I've got a GET oData request to the server. How could I work this out?
Thank you.

Comment: Where abouts is the `.show()` code? Are you sure it exists in the DOM when the code is executed?

Comment: When I click on the button, the first thing I did is `$(loadingImageId).show` but not joy. In the piece of coding above If I replace `fadeIn()` with `show()` it stops working. Well, when I debug the flow of execution, I can see that it steps into the queue(), at that very moment the image's style is set to "display:block" but the spinning wheel is not yet visible onto the screen.